# Add Arduino project to github

Tags: git, github, arduino

I am new to Arduino, and I am trying to add my Arduino code to a GitHub repository, but I can't find in the IDE a console to do to the push of the git to GitHub, any suggestions?

Comment: seems you're new to GitHub too, there is no difference in pushing your projects to GitHub whether it's Arduino or whatever project you're doing, you could use this link for a tutorial https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/git-push-pull.
if you're new to using the terminal too then GitHub has got that covered, you can drag and drop your code directly to your repository

Comment: You can use any console, you just need to install GIT in your PC. Some good options are: the Windows native shell , GitBash, CygWin, MSYS2 .. (I really like GitBash :) ) ... But as it's been explained, this has nothing to do with ardruino

Comment: thank you all!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) on your computer. Then you can either work via console or a GUI client (some notable examples here: [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)), which is probably preferred if you're new to the Git environment.
There is also this [great tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) where you can start from.

Answer (score 0):

You could push the Project to your Github Repo via the GitBash Terminal.
Otherwise just use the github gui to upload the files on the website